# Closed form solution for ${d \operatorname{Tr}(A\log(X))\over dX}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, logarithms, trace

I need a closed form solution for  ${d \operatorname{Tr}(A\log(X))\over dX}$. Here $A, X$ are $n\times n$ matrices, $\log$ is the matrix logarithm. 
${d \operatorname{Tr}(\log(X))\over dX}=X^{-1}$, but ${d \operatorname{Tr}(A\log(X))\over dX}$ seems to me much more complicated. This is not equal to $A X^{-1}$ as it may seem.
The best I derived so far is the following:
we have
$$
\log(X)=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over i}(I-X)^i
$$
Let's define  $Z=I-X$ and then
$$
d \log(X)=\log(X+dX)-\log(X)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over i} \sum_{k=1}^i 
Z^{i-k}dX Z^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \big(\sum_{i=k}^\infty {1\over i}Z^{i-k} dX \big)Z^{k-1}
$$
So
$$
d \operatorname{Tr}(A\log(X)) = \operatorname{Tr}(Ad\log(X))=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{Tr}\big(Z^{k-1} A \sum_{i=k}^\infty {1\over i}Z^{i-k}dX\big)
$$
Thus
$$
{d \operatorname{Tr}(A\log(X))\over dX}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \big(Z^{k-1} A\sum_{i=k}^\infty{1\over i}Z^{i-k}\big)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \big((I-X)^{k-1} A\sum_{i=k}^\infty{1\over i}(I-X)^{i-k}\big)
$$
It is reduced to $AX^{-1}$ only in the case when $AX=XA$

Comment: Hm, I have doubts that your formula has a closed form. Might be useful to check at mathoverflow, your problem looks more like a research-level problem.